# Error while migrating in Laravel database on heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku, laravel-9

When running heroku run php artisan migrate I get this error, I want to host my app on heroku

```
In Connection.php line 712

SQLSTATE[42804]: Datatype mismatch: 7 ERROR:  column "price" cannot be cast automatically to type numeric
  HINT:  You might need to specify "USING price::numeric(15,2)". (SQL: ALTER TABLE purchases ALTER price TYPE NUMERIC
  (15, 2))

In Connection.php line 501:

  SQLSTATE[42804]: Datatype mismatch: 7 ERROR:  column "price" cannot be cast automatically to type numeric
  HINT:  You might need to specify "USING price::numeric(15,2)".
```

purchase table

```
lass ChangePurchasePriceDataTyp extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('purchases', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->numeric('price',15,2)->unsigned()->default(0)->change();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('purchases', function (Blueprint $table) {
            //
        });
    }
}
```

database.php

```
'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => isset($DATABASE_URL['host']) ? $DATABASE_URL['host'] : null,
            'port' => isset($DATABASE_URL['port']) ? $DATABASE_URL['port'] : null,
            'database' => isset($DATABASE_URL['path']) ? ltrim($DATABASE_URL['path'], "/") : null,
            'username' => isset($DATABASE_URL['user']) ? $DATABASE_URL['user'] : null,
            'password' => isset($DATABASE_URL['pass']) ? $DATABASE_URL['pass'] : null,
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],
```

what could be wrong? initial the datatype was decimal but I changed it to numeric

Comment: Without more information we can't tell you anything more than the error message says. Are you using Postgres in development too, or are you using a different database like SQLite?

Comment: I am using Postgres @Chris